# How do I get two images to fit any screen size in html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize, viewport

This is my first attempt at writing html so apologies in advance for any beginner-ish mistakes.

I want 2 images of equal size to sit in horizontal alignment in desktop/laptop and tablet browser windows, then once the screen switches to a mobile 'portrait' view I want the two images to align vertically, but still be entirely visible (i.e. the scroll bar does not appear).

I have got the first part of this working nicely by placing each image in a separate div and using flexbox. These two divs are within a container div. They are centering when in this view. Once the browser window gets too narrow the second image is placed below the first as expected, but it moves out of view. How can I ensure the images are resized to both remain in view the whole time?

```
  <style type="text/css">    
    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .call-outs-container {
      min-height: 100vh;
      height:auto !important;
      height:100vh;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      max-width: 2800px;
    }

    .pics {
      padding:20px;
      box-sixing: border-box;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      flex-basis: 50%;
    }
    img {
      max-width:100%;
      height:100%;
      object-fit:contain;
    }

    @media (min-width: 700px) {
      .call-outs-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="call-outs-container">

      <div class = "pics">
        <img src="images/temp_spectra.jpeg" alt="Spectra Image" />
      </div>
      <div class = "pics">
        <img src="images/temp_sl.png" alt="Spectra Image" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Following requests - here's a JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/tullfan/t9hope6f/

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your example? Some of us (including me) are lazy to create a reproducible example but are willing to take a look if such an example exists.

Comment: Ok, @LajosArpad , I've created one here - changed the code slightly to use weblinks for images rather than upload originals from source folder. jsfiddle.net/tullfan/t9hope6f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height) size for the height to use 50% of the whole view height by each of the 2 pictures. To fit the scale factor just set width to auto and the browser resizes the width so that the scale factor is same:

```
img {
    height: 50vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this resolve your problem. I made some changes. Try this code:

```
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .call-outs-container{
    display: flex;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px){
    .call-outs-container{
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

And not forgot to add viewport in head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for something like this.
Made some changes. Please check it out.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
}

.call-outs-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pics {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*margin: 0 10px; /* change margin as needed*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .call-outs-container {
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="call-outs-container">

      <div class="pics">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      </div>
      <div class="pics">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Check this in your local

Comment: Using ``@media (min-width: 700px)`` seems wrong.  The "700" is far too arbitrary for this to be considered responsive.   It could in fact end up doing the opposite of what is needed (e.g. consider two devices, one whose longer edge triggers the 700 and one whose smaller edge triggers the 700).  What is of actual significance in this question is whether the window is tall or wide.  The @media test for "aspect-ratio" is exactly what is needed, and eliminates any assumptions about the size of the viewing device.

Comment: Hey @pasanjg , thanks for the rewrite. It doesn't seem to be working for me - in landscape it now hugs to the top left of the screen rather than the center and the images still exceed the browser window in portrait. This might be something I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks @RayButterworth , I get what you're saying. I'll look into tying it to aspect ratio instead.